# Writing to Direct Message as Slack bot without Invite

Tags: chatbot, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I have an app on Slack with a Bot user.

I already have the following usage pattern implemented and it works perfectly with channels. However, it doesn't work in Direct Messages.

1. User uses my slash command (/mycommand)
2. I return an ephemeral message with a preview of text to send, effectively "Random word"
3. Users can Cancel / Shuffle / or Send. (Cancel deletes the ephemeral message. This works in channels and DMs. Shuffle updates the ephemeral message in-place. This also works. Send will delete the ephemeral message and that chat.postMessage as the Bot. This works in channels, but not in DMs. The preview disappears and nothing is written to replace it.)

Because the action starts with a slash command, I'd hope the user intent is preserved as temporary auth. I think the ephemeral message erases this context and prevents me from writing directly to the DM with having the Bot user invited. Adding the Bot to the channel, turning it into a Multi-User Direct Message does work. However, it's a poor user experience because the humans lose their conversation history just to let a Bot talk.

An example of an App that implements the behavior I want is GIF Keyboard. (Just randomly found, not actually similar to my app.) https://realtalk-headquarters.slack.com/apps/A0FLZ2GVB-gif-keyboard (Their scopes: commands, bot, chat:write:bot, users:read, users:read.email )

It seems the secret sauce there is the "bot" scope which works only with classic tokens (which I don't think I can get anymore.)

Some apps seem to handle this via a user-token so they can instead post as the user. Ideally, I don't want to do that. I'm able to invite the Bot to a Direct Message and then everything works. This isn't great since we start a brand new message, just for the Bot, and lose all conversation history.

Is this possible anymore? It seems like the classic bots are able to support a better user experience in a way that new bots can't.

Thanks!